# How to calculate iteration of gauss siedel method in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate i´the number of iteration of gauss siedel method in matlab

here is my code

```
alpha=1;
A=zeros(30,30);
A(1,1)=-(2+alpha);
A(1,2)=1;

for i=2:29
    A(i,i-1)=1;
    A(i,i)=-(2+alpha);
    A(i,i+1)=1;
end

A(30,29)=1;
A(30,30)=-(2+alpha);

D=diag(diag(A));
R=A-D;
x=zeros(30,1);
list=[];
count=0;

for k=1:150
    xkk= inv(L)*(b-(U*x));
    count=count+1;
    list(count,:)=xk;
    if(norm(xkk-x)<=10^-5)
        break;
    end
    x=xkk;
end

count
```

when I ran it I got `cound=150` so it seems that count does not works good
How to correct it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last part like this:

```
xkk= inv(L)*(b-(U*x));
e=norm(xkk-x);
while(e>10^-5)
    xkk= inv(L)*(b-(U*x));
    count=count+1;
    list(count,:)=xk;
    e=norm(xkk-x)
    x=xkk;
end
```